# What dependency to use for Firestore with App Engine Node.js backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

My goal is to implement a backend service in Node.js in Google App Engine with sessions, user authentiation and a basic API for user data. I want to use Firebase for authentication and Firestore for storing the user data.

I have been reading the Google documentation for Node.js. I am utterly confused about the differences between

- Firebase,
- Firestore,
- Firestore in native mode,
- Firestore in Datastore mode and
- Google Cloud Datastore.

When I navigate in the `Google Cloud Platform` to `Datastore`, it tells me

> You’re using Cloud Firestore in Native mode
>   You can always go straight to the Firestore page from the main navigation to access your database.

I want to follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/session-handling-with-firestore) for implementing sessions since it works fine already. For authentication there is no guide in Node.js for App Engine.

I have two options:

- npm install firebase-admin --save, [guide and dependency](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data)
- npm install @google-cloud/firestore, [guide and dependency](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

### My very focused question

- What dependency should I use?

Comment: I ended upo using `firebase-admin`. Can't answer because the question got closed <.<

Answer (score 3):

Just to clear a bit more about these because I know it can be confusing:

- Firebase is a different platform from GCP, it does share some resources and some tools, but the focus is more regarding just coding and storage of data rather than all the thing you can do in GCP.
- Firestore is the "new" database that was launched in Firebase for strong consistency, scalability and it's noSQL
- Google Cloud Datastore: Is the original scalable noSQL solution that was launched on GCP, it has eventual consistency and high performance
- Firestore in native mode: So, here is were it gets tricky, Firestore in "native mode" is just normal Firestore BUT on GCP projects, not on Firebase. After some time, they saw that Datastore and Firestore were pretty much the same thing but Firestore was a bit better, so they decided to migrate Datastore to Firestore and that's why their documentation is so mixed.
- Firestore in Datastore mode: This is Firestore but with the behaviours of Datastore like eventual consistency and so on.

The differences are covered more in depth over [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore#in_native_mode), but for most cases it's better to jump directly to Firestore as it's backwards compatible with Datastore and solves some issues such as the eventual consistency.

As for which node dependency you should use, I would go with Firebase just because the documentation is a bit more clear and there are more examples of usage, but it's really up to you.